# List object members and values

Tags: vb.net

I have a 3rd party object that gets passed to one of my methods. The object contains 20 or so string members. How can I easily list all of the string names and their values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about properties? If so, you can use reflection:

```
Dim properties = theObject.GetType().GetProperties()
For Each prop In properties
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, _
        prop.GetValue(theObject, New Object() { }))
Next
```

This returns all public properties of the object via [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use `o.GetType().GetProperties()`
Then, use the `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` property to make sure it's a string,
Then, foreach property, call `GetValue (o, null)`

```
props = o.GetType().GetProperties()
PropertyInfo prop = props(0)
Console.WriteLine (prop.Name & " = " & prop.GetValue (o, Nothing))
```

Comment: `If prop.PropertyType == TypeOf(string)`